# Tools for finding how much a site is SEO compliant

Tags: seo

Are there any tools for finding if a page is SEO complaint and if it's not then suggest something to make that page SEO complaint?

Also note that I want to do this research on offline pages i.e. these pages are not on web yet.

Comment: There is no such thing as "SEO compliance."

Comment: @Justin, may be I don't now the exact terms...but I think I was successful in conveying what exactly I wanted, the answers says that... ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The best all purpose services are:

- [WooRank](http://www.woorank.com)
- [WebsiteGrader](http://websitegrader.com)
- Xinu

Google has their own tools which as close as you can get to official 'compliance':

- [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/siteoverview?pli=1)
- [Google Website Optimizer](http://services.google.com/websiteoptimizer/?sourceid=awo&subid=na-en-ha-wo-content&medium=ha)
- [Google Adwords Keywords Tool](https://adwords.google.com/select/KeywordToolExternal)

SEO is an entire industry, and the rules are always changing.
(See [here](http://boagworld.com/marketing/google-changes) for a great list of some of the more pronounced changes on Google this year.

And [here](http://www.onlinemarketing.co.il/%d7%94%d7%90%d7%9d-%d7%a6%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%9a-%d7%9c%d7%94%d7%aa%d7%97%d7%99%d7%9c-%d7%9c%d7%94%d7%aa%d7%a8%d7%97%d7%a7-%d7%9e%d7%92%d7%95%d7%92%d7%9c/) for some of the more noticeable differences from Bing.)

Some of the better SEO targeted sites are:

- [Web-strategist](http://www.web-strategist.com/blog/)
- [webanalyticsbook](http://www.webanalyticsbook.com/)
- [SeoBook](http://seobook.com)
- [Viget](http://www.viget.com/engage/P0/)

A monitoring service you should look at:

- http://conjection.net/

One of the better articles I would recommend is:
 - http://community.seobook.com/45711-post172.html

You should also make sure your page is loading optimally, it will effect the SEO even though it is its own field:
Load and performance - [Pingdom](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/) and [Uptrends](http://www.uptrends.com/aspx/free-html-site-page-load-check-tool.aspx).
If you are technically minded, install Yslow or PageSpeed and look at the score.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if "compliant" is the best term to use.  There isn't a standard.

Rather, there is a set of best practices that have been determined through observation of search engine behavior in reaction to certain aspects of page/url structure.

That being said, I would first take a look at article on About.com titled "[White Hat Vs. Black Hat SEO](http://advertising.about.com/od/onlineadvertising/a/whitehatvsblackhatseo.htm)"  You definitely want to avoid the black-tactics while abiding by the white-hat tactics.

In a nutshell, the focus on white-hat tactics is on quality content relevant to the subject.  Without that, your pages are pretty much dead in the water (assuming you don't subscribe to black-hat techniques).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Search Engine Optimization Toolkit](http://www.iis.net/expand/SEOToolkit). Tried it once and it works well.

> Got broken links on your site? Is your HTML SEO optimized? This fantastic free tool answers all these questions and hundreds more as it chews your angle brackets for you, creating flexible reports and a full queryable database of your site. -- [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ScottHanselmans2009UltimateDeveloperAndPowerUsersToolListForWindows.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late but I made a presentation with great tools for SEO that I used.

You will find a lot of Firefox Add-ons and Google Chrome Extensions to analyze your page and get suggestion to respect main search engines recommendations.

These slides also present other tools usefull for SEO expert like : google products, online services, wordpress plugins, ...

If it could help someone else, it's here : http://slidesha.re/KOoDad

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Offline tools, I did not know which will do this.
You could upload it for a short time or protect it with a password if you do not want that other people see the webpages.
Online-Tool: http://www.linkvendor.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following site useful with Keyword Destiny and more content driven queries in the past... http://www.seocentro.com/tools/seo/keyword-density.html

Answer (score 0):

i use this tool quite often. it doesn't look very good but i found the data to be really useful

[article underground keyword density tool](http://www.articleunderground.com/webmaster/keyword-density-tool.html)